# from a file convert binary to decimal

Tags: c++, binary

Hello guys i have a problem. I have a program which is converting binary  numbers to decimal. But i would like to convert a binary numbers from a file. For example in my txt file are binary numbers like that :
10000111001
10001000100
100010110
100001000
00010010011
And i would like to open this txt file in my program and convert this numbers to decimal
I 've created something like that but its not saving my outputs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int bin2dec(string binary)
{
    int decimal = strtol(binary.c_str(), NULL, 2);

    return decimal;
}

int main()
{
    string number;

    ifstream one("data.txt") //here are mine binary numbers
    ofstream two("second.txt") // i would like to save my converted numbers in this file
        while (!one.eof())
        {
            one >> number;
            number = bin2dec(number);
            two << number;

        }


    system("pause >nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `std::stoll` to convert the strings of binary data to integers. A basic example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void convbin(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os) {
    std::string bin;
    while(is >> bin) {        // extract word from "is"
        // Try to convert bin to a long long using base 2 (binary).
        // There's no error handling here and it may throw exceptions if it fails.

        os << std::stoll(bin, 0, 2) << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream one("data.txt");
    std::ofstream two("second.txt");

    if(one && two) convbin(one, two);
    else           std::cerr << "Error opening a file or both\n";
}
```

Comment: I know that now. But how to load a file into this line"std::istringstream one("10000111001 10001000100 100010110 100001000 00010010011");" I mean 
instead of these binary numbers. That there would be a text file with them

Comment: @Virozz I've updated the answer to make it clearer.